# I'm getting an error [ReflectionException] Class App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\TagsController does not exist when I run php artisan route:list

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting an error [ReflectionException] Class App\Http\Controllers\Frontend\TagsController does not exist when I run php artisan route:list

some one help.

[image: error screen shot]

Comment: Please show how do you use `TagsController` in the routes file and namespace of the controller.

Comment: Check you have properly namespaced your controller.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin Route::resource('tags', 'TagsController');

Comment: @PatrickMutwiri do you use it inside some route groups? Please show namespace of the controller.

Comment: Nop. independently in use.

Comment: I think its because you not using TagsController 1st comment route for TagsController and then try again hope it will show you route list

Comment: ok. let me try.

Answer (score 1):

Try namespace like this, in the controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Frontend;
```